# How does rc-prefix work in SuSE?

Tags: suse

`SuSE version is SuSE10 SP2`

If I want to manage some service, for example, named, I have several choices.

`choice 1. /etc/init.d/named status`

`choice 2. service named status`

`choice 3. rcnamed status`

These 3 commands have the exactly same return. I understand choice 1 and 2, but how does rc-prefix work in choice 3? anybody know this?

Answer (score 1):

The third one is a SuSE-ism which is typically a symlink to the appropriate `/etc/init.d` file for historical reasons.  (SuSE took its service management originally from BSD-influenced OSF/1, and still retains some of those behaviors.  I haven't checked to see if SuSE 10 still has the OSF/1-ish `/sbin/init.d` symlink as well as the ones you mentioned.)

Comment: yes, exactly, there is one separate symlink for each /etc/init.d/ service daemon.